# WPF Animation crash on collapsed element but not on hidden element

Tags: wpf, animation, crash, visibility

Why does animation fail on collapsed controls and not on hidden controls?

Concrete, in WPF I have a custom made checkbox with animation whereby the visibility is dynamically linked to the “setVisible” resource element (very simplified this looks like this).

```
<local:MyCheckBox x:Name="checkNonVisual" Visibility="{DynamicResource setVisible}" />
```

In the code I set the value of the checkNonVisual to true, false or null and this triggers
a small animation on the checkbox.

This works when the visibility of the element / “setVisible” resource element is set to Visibility.Visible and Visibility.Hidden, but it crashes when the visibility is set to Visibility.Collapsed with the error show below.

Can anyone explain me why the animation fails when the visibility is collapsed and why the animation does not fail when the visibility is hidden?

If I want to continue using collapsed, how can I prevent the animation from running so it does not crash anymore?

*Extract of Stacktrace:*

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
> Message='Check' name
> cannot be found in the name scope of
> 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.
> Source=PresentationFramework
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ResolveTargetName(String
> targetName, INameScope nameScope, DependencyObject element)
>
> at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock
> currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope,
> DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath
> parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary
> clockMappings, Int64 layer)
>
> [...]
>
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> [...]